# listing shared memory objects on Solaris by name

Tags: c, solaris, posix, shared-memory

I can use ipcs(1) to list out the active shared memory objects on a Solaris 10 box, but it lists them by key.  I'm opening the objects via shm_open(3), though, which takes a character string as a name to identify the object.  Is there a way to list the shared memory objects by name, or to just get the key<->name mapping?  I'm mostly interested in something to run from the command line, although an API for doing this would be OK, too.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like my assumption that there is a 1-to-1 mapping between keys and names was incorrect. Another way to ask this ... In Linux I can do:

`ls -l /dev/shm`

and see the info I'm trying get under Solaris 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember POSIX shared memory under Solaris appears on the file system either directly under `/tmp/` as `.SHMDxxx` files or under `/var/tmp/.SHMD/`. This might or might not help you and I don't have a Solaris box handy to validate.

Comment: Yep, `/tmp/.SHMD*` on my machine.  So I was thinking their was something magical about shm_open(3), but looks like it's probably just a wrapper around open(2) that creates the backing file on an appropriate file system?  Thanks!

Comment: shm_open returns the "file" descriptor after all, which you are supposed to mmap. I might be mistaken but I guess this is done as some sort of a VFS hack (need to look into Solaris sources for this :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a way to list names or get key/name mappings. But I think I know an API that will solve your problem.

I think you can attach the segment from the key by using the System V interface, which is also a Posix API.  I believe the way it works is something like:

```
int attach_shmem(key_t key, void** pp){
    void* p;
    int id;

    id = shmget(key, 0, 0);
    if (id < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        return ERR_SHMGET;
    }
    p = shmat(id, 0, 0);
    if ((long)p == -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        return ERR_SHMAT;
    }
    *pp = p;
    return 0;
}
```